# Restore functionality to press home button to go to home screen

Tags: 8.0-oreo, home-button, samsung-galaxy-a3

On my Samsung Galaxy A3 (2017) with Android 8, I used to be able to press the home button to directly go to the home screen.

Some configuration must have changed because now when I press the home button, it only activates the screen but doesn't take me to the home screen.

I need to press the home button to activate the screen and then swipe to go the home screen.

Anyone can help me restore the previous functionality?

Comment: Did the old behavior you mention (go to the home screen) occur when the screen was on, off, or both?

Comment: When it was off. I would press Home button once to enable screen and then a second time to show the pin lock screen. Once entered the PIN, it would take me directly to the home screen.